# SQL Server 2008 Swedish / Finnish collation

Tags: sql-server-2008, collation

Is `Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS` collation backed by a Latin-1 translation? Anyone have a good translation list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe not, only Latin1_General_CI_AS is Latin-1

There is a good list here, thanks to google: 
http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/change-database-collation.aspx

**Collation names:**

***(Language = Collation)***

```
Afrikaans = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Albanian = Albanian_CI_AS 
Arabic (Algeria) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Bahrain) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Egypt) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Iraq) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Jordan) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Kuwait) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Lebanon) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Libya) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Morocco) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Oman) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Qatar) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Saudi Arabia) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Syria) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Tunisia) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (U.A.E.) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Arabic (Yemen) = Arabic_CI_AS 
Armenian (Republic of Armenia) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Azeri-Cyrillic (Azerbaijan)1 = Azeri_Cyrillic_90_CI_AS 
Azeri-Latin (Azerbaijan)1 = Azeri_Latin_90_CI_AS 
Basque = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Belarusian = Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
Bulgarian = Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
Catalan = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Chinese (Hong Kong S.A.R.)1 = Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90_CI_AS 
Chinese (Macau S.A.R.)2 = Chinese_PRC_90_CI_AS 
Chinese (PRC)2 = Chinese_PRC_CI_AS 
Chinese (PRC) = Chinese_PRC_Stroke_CI_AS 
Chinese (Singapore) = Chinese_PRC_90_CI_AS 
Chinese (Taiwan) = Chinese_Taiwan_Stroke_CI_AS 
Chinese (Taiwan) = Chinese_Taiwan_Bopomofo_CI_AS 
Croatian = Croatian_CI_AS 
Czech = Czech_CI_AS 
Danish = Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS 
Divehi1 = Divehi_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Dutch (Belgium) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Dutch (Netherlands) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Australia) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Belize) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Canada) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Caribbean) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Hong Kong S.A.R.) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (India) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Indonesia) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Ireland) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Jamaica) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Malaysia) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (New Zealand) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Philippines) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Singapore) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (South Africa) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (Trinidad) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (United Kingdom) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
English (United States) = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
English (Zimbabwe) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Estonian = Estonian_CI_AS 
Faeroese = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Farsi = Arabic_CI_AS 
Finnish = Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS 
French (Belgium) = French_CI_AS 
French (Canada) = French_CI_AS 
French (France) = French_CI_AS 
French (Luxembourg) = French_CI_AS 
French (Monaco) = French_CI_AS 
French (Switzerland) = French_CI_AS 
Galician (Spain) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Georgian = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
German (Austria) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
German (Germany) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
German (Liechtenstein) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
German (Luxembourg) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
German (Phone Book Sort) = German_PhoneBook_CI_AS 
German (Switzerland) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Greek = Greek_CI_AS 
Gujarati (India)3 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Hebrew = Hebrew_CI_AS 
Hindi3 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Hungarian = Hungarian_CI_AS 
Hungarian (Technical) = Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS 
Icelandic = Icelandic_CI_AS 
Indonesian = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Italian (Italy) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Italian (Switzerland) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Japanese = Japanese_CI_AS 
Kannada (India)3 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Kazakh (Kazakstan)1 = Kazakh_90_CI_AS 
Konkani (India)3 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Korean (Extended Wansung) = Korean_Wansung_CI_AS 
Kyrgyz-Cyrillic (Republic of Kyrgyztan) = Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
Latvian = Latvian_CI_AS 
Lithuanian = Lithuanian_CI_AS 
Macedonian (FYROM) = Macedonian_FYROM_90_CI_AS 
Malay (Brunei Darussalam) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Malay (Malaysia) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Marathi (India)3 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Mongolian-Cyrillic (Mongolia) = Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
Norwegian (Bokmal) = Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS 
Norwegian (Nynorsk) = Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS 
Polish = Polish_CI_AS 
Portuguese (Brazil) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Portuguese (Portugal) = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Punjab-Gurmuhki (India)3 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Romanian = Romanian_CI_AS 
Russian = Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
Sanskrit (India)3 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Serbian (Cyrillic) = Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
Serbian (Latin) = Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
Slovak = Slovak_CI_AS 
Slovenian = Slovenian_CI_AS 
Spanish (Argentina) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Bolivia) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Chile) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Colombia) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Costa Rica) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Dominican Republic) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Ecuador) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (El Salvador) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Guatemala) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Honduras) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (International Sort) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Mexico) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Nicaragua) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Panama) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Paraguay) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Peru) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Puerto Rico) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Traditional Sort) = Traditional_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Uruguay) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Spanish (Venezuela) = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS 
Swahili = Latin1_General_CI_AS 
Swedish = Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS 
Swedish (Finland) = Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS 
Syriac (Syria)1 = Syriac_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Tamil (India)1 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Tatar (Tatarstan)1 = Tatar_90_CI_AS 
Telugu (India)1 = Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only) 
Thai = Thai_CI_AS 
Turkish = Turkish_CI_AS 
Ukrainian = Ukrainian_CI_AS 
Urdu = Arabic_CI_AS 
Uzbek (Latin)1 = Uzbek_Latin_90_CI_AS 
Uzbek-Cyrillic (Republic of Uzbeckistan) = Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
Vietnamese = Vietnamese_CI_AS
```